# how to retrieve data in DataGridView fast from MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

i want to know how to retrieve data in datagridview fast from mssql. like when i run my program my grid starts with filling the data and it's quite slowly like i can see the filling process it's just take 2 seconds but i want it to do fast like in nano seconds . anyone let me know how to do this. by the way it's desktop application develop on C# and project is barcode based point of sale system

private void FillGrid()
        {

```
        DataTable xTable = new DataTable();
        new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblProducts order by BID DESC",xConn).Fill(xTable);
        DGV1.DataSource = xTable;
        DGV1.Columns[0].Width = 50;
        DGV1.Columns[1].Width = 100;
        DGV1.Columns[2].Width = 150;
        DGV1.Columns[3].Width = 50;

        for (int i = 0; i < DGV1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
        {                
            int QTY = Int32.Parse(DGV1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
            if(QTY >=21 && QTY <= 50)
            { 
                DGV1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                DGV1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Bold);
            }
            else if (QTY >= 0 && QTY <= 20)
            { DGV1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
            DGV1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Bold);
            }

            { DGV1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
            DGV1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Bold);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you want to provide any code for us or are we supposed to just point you to the easy button? Seriously without any details how do you expect this to generate an answer?

Comment: What is taking 2 Seconds where's the code ?

Comment: @Krishna code posted

Comment: First remove that loop and perform those operations either in data grid row created or row bound which will improve it up to some extent

Comment: There are several probabilities here. First, you should NOT use select *. Only select the columns you actually need. How many rows are there? Can you share the table definition? How long does that query take by itself in SSMS?

Comment: on server studio it works fast but when i call it on grid it takes 2 seconds to fill the grid like vertically data appears .. i'm working on pos , this part is of enter new products

Comment: @Krishna this loop is used to show the quantity alerts of stock like whenever any product that quantity have 0-20 it will be appear RED color in grid but only that specific quantity row not all like that product name etc

Comment: I understand that but you can do it in row bound which is better as it will run for every row

Comment: how to do this can you explain me kindly @Krishna

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, stored procedure are faster than the function, use them !
furthermore if you can share the code or some scenario details, so i can easily solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you can do

**First** 
remove column width in the fill because you don't need to set it every time you fill the grid which is unnecessary, move that code designer or do it in the windows design directly

**Second**
Move column formatting to Datagridview Cell Formatting as below, by this you can avoid the default formatting and then your formation twice

```
private void DGV1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    int QTY = Int32.Parse(DGV1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
        if(QTY >=21 && QTY <= 50)
        { 
            DGV1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            DGV1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Bold);
        }
        else if (QTY >= 0 && QTY <= 20)
        { 
          DGV1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
          DGV1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Bold);
        }
        else
        { 
          DGV1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
          DGV1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Bold);
        }
}
```